# Can i override the select event on the content assist?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

I am Implementing a plugin to override the common java Proposals on eclipse. Can I override the select event on the content assist ? How?

Comment: You can add to the proposals using the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer` extension point. Replacing the proposals altogether is much more difficult.

Comment: Hi @greg-449. Yes, i added my proposals on a new category proposals using org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer. But i want to Implement a new behavior for event that selects a proposal from the list proposals. Do you understand me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution. I created a class that implements org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ICompletionProposal and override the method "public void apply ( IDocument document) " as i want that the editor does when a proposal is selected. Then i used my implementation to create the completion proposals on the content assist processor.